# get JSON data from url with php and curl

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to display data from JSON in a php script. If i visit the link myself, i will get this:

```
{"SYSINFO":{"STATE":"RUN"}}
```

I need to get this in a PHP script. I tried the following code:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://192.168.0.200/api/get/data?elm=STATE", 'jsonp');
$utf8 = utf8_decode($json); //decode UTF-8
$data = json_decode($utf8, true);

echo $data['SYSINFO']['STATE'];
```

I am using an easyE4 from Eaton with a webclient. On the site it says

> cURL command prompt commands
>   You can send all JSON API calls via command shell by using the HTTP request syntax using cURL. For authentication username+password or API key can be used.
>
> Example call username + password
>   Syntax:
>   curl --user “:” “http:////?"
>   Example:
>   curl --user “admin:myAdminPassword$19” “http://10.235.2.244/api/get/data?elm=STATE"
>   In the above call, we can also add username and password to HTTP header in base64 encoded format and then talk to device. For e.x. if our username is “admin” and password is “Admin@123”. Then the string “admin:Admin@123” will be “YWRtaW46QWRtaW5AMTIz” in base 64 encoding. In this case the request would be as below:

How can I get this data using PHP?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try?

Comment: What do you think `utf8_decode` does, and why do you think it's needed here? Also, not sure what you think the second argument to `file_get_contents` is, but it's not that.